# Unable to do git clone Linux kernel repo using egit in windows

Tags: eclipse, git

I am trying to clone gitolite repo using EGit on my windows PC.
    I am able to clone the Linux kernel git repo from command line in windows
    git clone **gitolite@server:linux.git**

```
When i am trying to do from Egit. It is giving me below error
**gitolite@server:linux.git** has encountered a problem
Invalid path: drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/core/subdev/i2c/aux.c
```

Not sure why this is giving invalid path..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As mentioned here](https://superuser.com/q/86999/141), "`aux`"  is reserved by Windows.
[Even "`aux.xxx`", as Microsoft points out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Also avoid these names followed immediately by an extension; for example, `NUL.txt` is not recommended".

The clone might work from a git *bash* session, but not from a windows Egit/JGit clone (which is pure Windows).

Comment: Thanks Vonc, I removed aux.c which is not required in my project and i am able to clone now successfully

Comment: The clone does not work from a git bash session as of today, with `git version 2.30.0.windows.2`. Same failure as OP.

Comment: @studog OK. Could you try the same clone from a WSL2 Linux session, if you are on Windows 10? There you would have a full-fledged bash session.

Comment: @VonC I will if I ever have WSL2 installed.